# Looking for a non-kink hose and variable spray nozzle with NO LEAKS

Tags: watering, hoses

I'm interested in your opinions about the best nonleaking hose nozzle. I love all the different variable sprays and I do use them. But it drives me crazy when it drips on my feet. I've probably tried a dozen types.

Also, every hose I buy will kink at one point.  I love the little shrinking hose but that cannot be left in the sun because it springs leaks so it isn't the most convenient.  I'd like to hear what others think.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I think the way this was written puts it off-topic. According to this [help](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page, "what's your favorite" and related questions asking "what people think" should be avoided. If you'd like to re-word it to ask what type of nozzle or hose is least likely to leak, or the best way to prevent leaks, I think it would be okay. I could be misinterpreting that page though, and am only one member of the community.

Comment: This [related question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/what-sort-of-hose-nozzle-should-i-look-for-such-that-it-wont-spring-a-leak-afte?rq=1) may help you either with your nozzle problem, or with  assistance in editing your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garden hoses are completely on-topic! Any headache will become a negative link between a human and the garden. Get the length you need, make sure you get the THICKEST and most expensive you are able to afford and then save money on the cheapest oscillating sprinkler you can find.  Weird, huh! The $7.00 oscillating sprinklers found at Lowes, Home Depot or you friendly Ace Hardware store is the BEST!  I've tried the expensive ones and they are a third that these cheap ones can deliver.  You can always purchase new ones for the price of the expensive sprinklers.  I prefer these to automated irrigation systems!

Hoses...if you are watering your vegetable garden, the dog's bowl, drinking out of most hoses, most hoses contribute lots of carcinogens. Check out the fine print when shopping for hoses! No big deal if you aren't ingesting or eating the plants you water.  Just FYI.  But the thicker, more expensive the hose that is labeled 'less likely to kink' is as good as one can do!  For vegetables, or sipping out of a hose make sure that it is a WHITE hose.  Those are supposed to be for RV's, Motorhomes or any time we animals drink the water delivered.

Wrap your hose when finished in the shade and in a figure 8.  Most nurseries do this.  Wrapping them up in a circle will cause them to adhere to a certain formation that if you try to change will cause kinks, cracks.  FIGURE 8.  Store in the garage during winter.  Otherwise, expect to replace every other year or so.